# how I call back function using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this validate function component how I can use It to return callback funcion?

the first file only for check validity

```
export function checkValidity(value, rules, shouldValidat) {
   let isValid = true;

    return isValid;
}
```

the second file caller

```
import { checkValidity } from "../UI/CheckValidity";
let res = checkValidity(vlaue, validationRules, shouldValidat);

callback = () =>{
   alert("call back function is done");
}
```

how I can call the callback function from the first file using react js?

Comment: pass callback as argument to checkvalidity and call it right before return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a callback in `checkValidity` function.

So you need to add `callback` as argument in `checkValidity(value, rules, shouldValidat, callback)` and then simply do:

```
export function checkValidity(value, rules, shouldValidat, callback) {
   let isValid = true;
   /*do your validation here and if it's okay then call callback*/
   callback();
   return isValid;
}
```

Comment: maybe return the value in the callback as well ?  callback(value)

Comment: let res = checkValidity(vlaue, validationRules, shouldValidat, this.callback);

Answer (score 1):

You should write a function which is like ;

```
callback(email) {
const re = ..... => it should be validation rule 
if(re.test) {
return email;
}
return false;
```

and when you call function in other function you should give your email or other params for function param .

Answer (score 0):

**Two callback examples:**

1. Callback when something is true `callback(isValid)`
2. Callback to deal with false (if needed) `errorcallback(isValid)`

   ```
   export const checkValidity = (value, rules, shouldValidate, callback, errorcallback) => {
       let isValid = true; // hardcoded
       isValid ? callback(isValid) : errorcallback(isValid)
       return isValid;
   }
   ```

**How to invoke**

Pass your functions as arguments 4 & 5, in this case, `callback` and `errorcallback`

`val` denotes a parameter passed back from the callback. in our example above were passing `isValid` which we are now calling `val` from where `checkValidity()` is invoked.

```
import { checkValidity } from "../UI/CheckValidity";
let res = checkValidity(value, validationRules, shouldValidate);

checkValidity(
    value,
    rules,
    shouldValidate,
    (val) => {console.log('callback() if true!! ' + val )},
    (val) => {console.log('errorcallback() if false!!' + val}
)
```